# ogr2ogr MSSQL to geopackage encoding

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, sql-server, geopackage

I'm exporting data from a MSSQL server to geopackage.

`"C:\OSGeo4W\bin\ogr2ogr.exe" -f "GPKG" "C:\folder\tables.gpkg" "MSSQL:server=theserver;database=thedb;driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;UID=username;PWD=password" -sql "SELECT * FROM tablea" -nln tablea`

The Swedish letters ÅÄÖ does not display correctly in QGIS, they are `?` signs:
[image]

The encoding is set to utf-8 in layer properties.

I've tried `-lco encoding=UTF-8` and `-lco encoding=LATIN-1` and casting the columns to text

`-sql "SELECT CAST(column1 AS TEXT) column1, ... FROM ...`

I get alot of:

> Warning 1: Value of field 'field1' is not a valid UTF-8 string.
> Warning 1: Value of field 'field2' is not a valid UTF-8 string.

when copying.

The features listed with ogrinfo have the same problem.

I've also tried copying from the mssql into a postgres db:

```
ERROR 1: Non UTF-8 content found when writing feature 42 of layer x
ERROR 1: Unable to write feature 42 from layer SELECT.
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation from sql statement.
```

Comment: I don't know anything about SQL server, but for Oracle we need to specify the localisation settings the database is configured in on the client we run ogr2ogr on to avoid issues like that. In oracle, for our situation, this is by setting the following environment variable `NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8` on the client. Maybe there is something similar for SQL Server?

Comment: So the problem is coming out of  MSSQL - is there a way to specify the character encoding inside the DB?

Comment: Seems like it. I dont know, I have no control over the database unfortunately. Maybe I need to contact the Server admins..

Comment: I think that the the first thing to do is to find out which character set the database is using internally. Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182164/sql-server-default-character-encoding.