# ogr2ogr MSSQL to gpkg encoding issue

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

I am trying to write data from SQL server to geopackage but I have met some encoding issues.

```
Warning 1: Value of field 'IDENTIFICATION' is not a valid UTF-8 string.
```

I dont understand where in the process I get this error? Is it when ogr2ogr is trying to read SQL server or write to gpkg? Worth mentioning, borth table name and table records can have non ascii characters.

```
ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" "c:\temp\tmp.gpkg" "MSSQL:server=server;database=db;tables='tbl1';trusted_connection=yes;" -overwrite -a_srs "EPSG:4326"
```

Comment: If it is a warning then it should not prevent the conversion. The message means that ogr2ogr has been reading some content from MSSQL that it believes to be something else than UTF-8. It can also be some invisible character. Usually GDAL is right, but not always. Try to identify the rows that triggers the warnings. Sometimes conversion into other formats like CSV, GML, or shapefile, helps with locating where the issue is.

Comment: The same problem in this question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/471808/ogr2ogr-mssql-to-geopackage-encoding.

Comment: Hmm I am pretty sure the encoding is Windows-1252. However I dont have a problem with all tables from the same database. Most of them are just fine . Typically tables with just ascii characters. With others I get issues- I do get a number of errors No column definitions found for table ''v_mytable'', layer not usable.